# What is the cup-product structure like on a hyperbolic 5-manifold?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, cup-product

Let $X$ be a hyperbolic 5-manifold.  Can there be any class in $H^2(X;\mathbf{Z})$ that is torsion and whose square in $H^4(X;\mathbf{Z})$ is not zero?

For example, are there hyperbolic 5-manifolds that have the same integer cohomology ring as $\mathbf{R}P^5$, or another 5d lens space?

Comment: You probably meant to assume that $X$ is closed or finite volume. In the arithmetic case a lot is known (even though I doubt that complete cohomology ring is ever computed). I would start from the seminal paper  [Millson, John J.
On the first Betti number of a constant negatively curved manifold.
Ann. of Math. (1976)] and use MathSciNet to trace references to the modern times.